# Pytest always fails the second time

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, pytest

Hi thank u for your time,

My PyTest always fail the second time on put request.

But when I try testing put using Postman, the issue didn't occur, I manage to put several requests consecutively.

But on PyTest testing, it is successful the first time but always fail the second time. I need to do modifications on JSON request every time for the put test to be successful. am really confuse, I don't know how to debug this.

I am using :
python 3.10
flask 2.1.2
sqlalchemy 1.4.39

```
@pytest.mark.asyncio
async def test_put_student():
    randomFavSub = ""
    randomFavSub = randomFavSub.join(random.choice(letters) for i in range(10))
    request_dict = {
        "user_id": "0e4c1d44-04f6-4a26-a02d-8e67a91b00f1",
        "fav_sub": "Subject" + randomFavSub
    }
    headers = {
        'content-type': 'application/json',
        'Accepts': 'application/json'
    }
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession(headers=headers) as session:
        await asyncio.sleep(5)
        async with session.put(URL + GLOBAL_ID, json=request_dict) as response:
            if response.status == 200:
                data = await response.json()
                data_student = data['student']
                data_student_first = data_student[0]
            else:
                data = await response.text()
                assert False, "modify Failure response is text " + str(response.status)

    # TODO #38 Generalize the assert to all conditions
    for key, value in request_dict.items():
        assert (value == data_student_first[key]), "modify FAILURE " + key
```

The GLOBAL_ID is retrieved from here

```
@pytest.mark.asyncio
async def test_post_student():
    request_dict = {
        "user_id": "0e4c1d44-04f6-4a26-a02d-8e67a91b00f1",
        "fav_sub": "Science"
    }

    global GLOBAL_ID
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        async with session.post(URL, json=request_dict) as response:
            if response.status == 200:
                data = await response.json()
                data_student = data['student']
                data_student_first = data_student[0]
                GLOBAL_ID = data_student_first['id']
                assert GLOBAL_ID, "GLOBAL_ID couldn't be created"
            else:
                data = await response.text()
                assert False, 'retrieve Failure response is text'

    for key, value in request_dict.items():
        assert value == data_student_first[key], "create FAILURE key"
```

I run post, get, update, delete request in that order.But only the update seems to fail.

Comment: `if response.status == 200:` you didn't await the response.status. Have a good read through the example here -> https://realpython.com/async-io-python/#a-full-program-asynchronous-requests

Comment: @Davos Hi, i can't await an int object. response.status is an int object.

Comment: The examples here https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/client_reference.html use `assert response.status == 200`

Comment: what message does it give while failing? did you try using `-vvv` for more verbosity? also try with `--showlocals` if you want to print some local vars..

Comment: @Shod ./pytest/test_student.py::test_put_student Failed: [undefined]AssertionError: modify Failure response is text 404

I set the error message to output this if the response.status is not 200
Apparently, i get the error, because the put response.status is not 200, ime suppose to have 200, then i can get the response.json() thats my final objective actually. actually ime not sure why it works for the first time, so i dont reckon any fault in the logic. But the second time i post, it get response.status 400

Comment: try to change `"modify Failure response is text " + str(response.status)` to `"modify Failure response is text " + str(response.text)`

this way, you will know what is the error text

Comment: @Shod here is the ouput : 

./pytest/test_student.py::test_put_student Failed: [undefined]AssertionError: modify Failure response is text {
      "message": "user doesn't exist, cannot update"
  }

So the user guid (GLOBAL_ID) doesn't exist when i pass this user_guid to the put endopint. But this is not the issue. The issue is, the pytest works sometime, but fail other time, even with the same code. I need to run multiple test to make it work. But this is counter productive, i want it to work all the time when ime not changing my code.

Comment: @Shod i modify the question to inclde the where i get the GLOBAL_ID

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually its a mistake from my part, in the put I have two sessions running causing the conflict. If others want details. I can explain further more.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).